# Asp.Net Profile Across Sub-Domains

Tags: asp.net, subdomain

Is there any way I access Profile information set in one sub-domain across another sub-domain? Or is the Profile information application specific?

I am setting profile values in one sub-domain and want to access that Profile on another sub-domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your applications specify the same applicationName value to the profile provider then they should access the same profile information as long as they agree on the user's identity.

If you're using forms authentication then you can ensure that the authentication cookie is visible to all applications with

```
<forms domain="parentdomain.com" ... />
```

Your applications will also need to share a machineKey to ensure that they can decrypt cookies created by the others.

If you're using anonymous identification then you can share those cookies too with

```
<anonymousIdentification domain="parentdomain.com" ... />
```